# tutorial to stream live video from ip camera to android app

Tags: android, ip, ip-camera

Please advise how can i go fulfiling the above task.Is there any tutorials or code segment which can be of help.

Thanks and Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to setup rtsp streaming in the server side and call out the url in the android app.